# msconfig overridden with restart

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, automation, msconfig

Several times I have gone to msconfig and unchecked SendIt from automatically starting with boot up. Several times, after a reboot, SendIt starts up and a box shows up. Am I doing something wrong or can YouSendIt override msconfig choices?

Comment: are you sure no updates to the application occurred? if the app schedules an update check, and installs an update, it would likely apply the reg keys to autostart the app again.

Comment: See if there's an option within the app to turn this off. Often if the app is set to auto-start, simply running it will restore the settings and undo any changes made externally by you via msconfig, regedit etc.

Comment: Yes! There was. I remember changing it long ago. I changed it again. I'm also wondering if the update does in fact restore this setting as a default. When I notice it automatically starting again, I'll go in and fix it. @Karan

Answer (score 0):

If one modifies some application start up option while the application is still running - it is easy for the application to check the setting and change it back.

Try changing the setting after you closed the application first.

Comment: I turned it off and went back to msconfig and it was still unchecked so that doesn't seem to be the case with YouSendIt. Thanks.

Comment: many such programs add themselves to multiple startup locations. so probably you just did not find all of them